# Docker: Container permanently restarting

Tags: python, bash, docker, containers

I'm new to the whole Docker Container topic and currently trying to run multiple python scripts in shell via bash script (cause it seemed to be the easiest thing to do in terms of running multiple python scripts at the same time). Before that I build my Image via the following Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

ENV PACKAGES1="build-essential git python3"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y $PACKAGES1 
    
COPY /mnt /mnt

CMD [ "/bin/bash", "/mnt/setup_bash.sh" ]
```

to execute the `setup_bash.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash

python3 script1.py & 
python3 script2.py &
```

after running the resulting container he keeps restarting and doesn't stay active. Meanwhile the `docker logs` command doens't display any errors so I'm kinda clueless what's the problem.

Comment: When the main process finishes, the container terminates. Since you're spawning the processes, and none of them is running as the main process, the container terminates.

Comment: Not seeing the part where it "keeps restarting", but it looks like it might not be "_waiting_" for the child processes to finish

Comment: Can you restructure this to launch one script per container, in two separate containers, without a launcher shell script?  Even though it needs two separate containers (and probably two separate images) having smaller single-purpose containers will wind up being easier to run and debug.

Comment: If you don't want the container to exit at all, assuming that the python scripts are launching some kind of service that  does something useful, you can put an infinite loop in your startup script to make sure the script never terminates. (May not be the ideal way, but could work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main process of the system exits, so docker is killed. You are running two processes in the background and the main bash scripts quits. You could:

- run one script on foreground, or
- run `sleep infinity` to keep the main script running
- refactor it all and for complex setups consider using service management, like `supervisord`

Like with option 2:

```
#! /bin/bash
python3 script1.py & 
python3 script2.py &
sleep infinity  # don't quit
```

Comment: Or you can just add a `wait` command instead of `sleep infinity`

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, if your script is exiting before the processes are finished, you can use the `wait` command to wait for all the scripts to finish before continuing.

```
#! /bin/bash

python3 script1.py & 
python3 script2.py &

wait

echo "Finished!"
```